# Software for achieving Automatic LevelGain between 2 AudioClips and Background Music

Tags: mixing

I am mixing for a 10hour long Audiobook.It consists of a vocal track and another for background music (mp3 file).
I wanted to add Automatic level gain to the background music (mp3 file) when the transition takes place between 2 dialogues .As seen in the pic ,each dialogue consists of an audioclip and should be raised whenever a transition takes place from one vocal clip to another.

I was looking for a software DAW/ plugin to achieve this .I tried 
Cakewalk(sidechain expresssion[image]) and Audacity however this kind of effect is not possible .Please let know of any software which could achieve this automated effect.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible using sidechain expression in Cakewalk, and similar in Ableton and Cubase.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a side-chain compressor with a slow attack and a fairly long release time. Drive the side-chain from the dialogue tracks. It may be necessary to use a compressor with look-ahead. Some delay might also be useful if the timing of the compressor action is a bit off.